# How to fix eval()() eval in Python3

Tags: python-3.x

This is the code from [GraphWave](https://github.com/snap-stanford/graphwave/blob/master/Using%20GraphWave.ipynb):

```
width_basis = 15
nbTrials = 20

### 1. Choose the basis (cycle, torus or chain)
basis_type = "cycle" 

### 2. Add the shapes 
n_shapes = 5  ## numbers of shapes to add 
#shape=["fan",6] ## shapes and their associated required parameters  (nb of edges for the star, etc)
#shape=["star",6]
list_shapes = [["house"]] * n_shapes

### 3. Give a name to the graph
identifier = 'AA'  ## just a name to distinguish between different trials
name_graph = 'houses'+ identifier
sb.set_style('white')
add_edges = 0
G, communities, _ , role_id = build_graph.build_structure(width_basis, basis_type, list_shapes, start=0,
                                       add_random_edges=add_edges, plot=True,
                                       savefig=False)
```

build_structure function:

```
def build_structure(width_basis, basis_type, list_shapes, start=0,
                    rdm_basis_plugins=False, add_random_edges=0,
                    plot=False, savefig=False):
    basis, role_id = eval(basis_type)(start, width_basis)
```

error when eval()():
name 'cycle' is not defined.

When I see the source code, the eval function is eval(). What's the mean of eval()() and how to fix this error?

Comment: `eval(basis_type)` is supposed to return a callable object. The *result* of `eval()` is then called.

Comment: What the code should instead be using is `globals()[basis_type]`, or better still, put all the possible types into a dictionary; `basis_types = {}`, with the string keys pointing to the callable objects.

Comment: That the evaluation fails only means that in the namespace where the `eval()` is executed, there is no name `cycle` defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tackeled the same problem with the same library:

First of, pay attention that the library supports python 2.7 and not 3.x like your tagging.

I changed the code to support python 3.5, and also the project files hierarchy and it worked for me.

In addition, for better practice, I removed the "eval" part, and used dictionary instead, like @Martijn Pieters suggested in the comments.